# AR 14 RDLX Reports display nested property

Tags: activereports

I'm using rdlx with json provider data to dataset

I have a class

```
Class A
{
string ID,
List<B> lstB
}
Class B
{
string C,
string D
}
```

I want display all C property inside lstB, how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I'm trying to do the same. Want to get a table in a table row to display a nested data set